# BitBlt in Qt4?

Tags: qt, qt4, bitblt

What is the recommended method of copying one QImage into another at a particular position in Qt4?

*QImage::bitblt* was removed in Qt4.

Does the QImage now need to be converted to a PixMap and back?

Answer (score 6):

Use QPainter to draw to your image.

```
QPainter painter( &targetImage );

painter.drawImage( ... );
```

Answer (score 4):

From Qt Assistant: "Use copy() or QPainter::drawImage() instead."

Comment: See also [here for QT-4](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qpainter.html#drawImage) and [here for QT-5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qpainter.html#drawImage).